# Should BizTalk 2009 be Windows Clustered?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

We are currently building out a Production BizTalk environment for high availability. We have built out several Dev and QA environments without issue, but none of these have been load balanced or clustered.

Should the BizTalk 2009 Production environment be Windows Clustered? According to the [Microsoft Tech Poster](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9729), it should be load balanced between two servers, but only clustered for certain adapters.

What is the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BizTalk 2009 should only be clustered if FTP and POP3 file pickup will be needed.

Comment: If you mean the host that runs them, yes they need to be clustered. Also WCF-SQL polling.